# calculating the area and perimeter of a rectangle drawn in graphics.py

Tags: python, graphics

I am trying to draw a rectangle with `graphics` using `getMouse` and then calculate its area and perimeter.

I have no idea how to calculate the area or perimeter. This is what I have so far.

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("rectangle",200,200)

text = Text(Point(100,50), "please click on two points.")
text.draw(win)

p1 = win.getMouse()
p2 = win.getMouse()

rectangle = Rectangle(p1,p2)
rectangle.draw(win)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two points as the diagonals, you can compute the lengths of the sides by taking the absolute value of the difference in x and the absolute value of the difference in y. That will give you the length and width of the rectangle.

e.g. `length = abs(p1.x - p2.x)`

From there you can compute the area and perimeter accordingly.

e.g. `area = length * width`